# How to open the application from push notification without creating another instance of the app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378897/launch-a-fragment-in-my-android-application-from-the-notification-bar) I asked how to open a `fragment` in my application from a push notification. I found the solution pretty easily, but now I'm faced with the problem that when I follow the push notification, another instance of the application is created.

I tried [the suggestions given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386916/956975), but adding `noHistory="true"` to the `activity` in the `AndroidManifest` file, caused the app to close when I didn't want it to close.

Following the steps below, I need all instances of the app to be closed at step 5. In fact, I need to not be creating a second instance of the app at step 4. How do I do this?

1. Open the app from applications menu -> see screen A.
2. Navigate from screen A to screen B.
3. Push notification arrives!
4. Open notifications drawer, follow notification into the app, see screen C.
5. Press the device's hardware back button until prompted to exit the application - say Yes!
6. See screen B -> where you were when you opened the notification!

This shows that a second instance of the application is created when you follow the notification while being somewhere in the application.

Why? 
And how do I kill the first instance of the application, or kill both instances of the application when prompted to close the application and saying Yes?
Or better yet, how do I NOT create two instances when following the notification into the app?

Comment: "when I follow the push notification, another instance of the application is created" -- no, there is not. In Android, there is at most one copy of an application process in memory. Starting an activity from a `BroadcastReceiver` will, however, create [another *task*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), because you will need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `Intent` used with `startActivity()`.

Comment: I further suggest that you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maybe a little late, to avoid the creation of a new instance of your activity you can add a "launchMode" in the AndroidManifest like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Went the notification is open the singleTop will bring the current instance of the activity instead of creating a new one.

See this link for more information about launchModes: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode